# Why is select tag in rails form not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

I have a user registration form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
        :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
        :id => "employer-form") do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <p><%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :title => "Enter email", :value =>"Enter Email", :class =>"field" %></p>

    <p><%= f.text_field :profile_name, :autofocus => true, :title => "Enter Username", :value => "Enter Username", :class =>"field" %></p>


    <p class="clearfix">
       <%= f.password_field :password, :title => "Enter Password", :value => "Enter Password", :class => "field field-half" %>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :title => "Retype Password", :value => "Retype Password", :class => "field field-half" %>     
    </p>

    <p class="clearfix"> 
       <%= f.text_field :first_name, :title => "Enter First Name", :value => "Enter First Name", :class => "field field-half" %>
       <%= f.text_field :last_name, :title => "Retype Last Name", :value => "Enter Last Name", :class => "field field-half" %>
    </p>

    <p class="clearfix">
       <div class="custom-select">
           <%= f.select_tag(:how_did_you_hear, options_for_select
               ([["Bing", :bing],["College Rep", :college_rep],
               ["Facebook", :facebook],["Google", :google],
               ["Pinterest", :pinterest],["Yahoo", :yahoo],
               ["Twitter", :twitter],["Other", :other]])) %>
       </div>  
    </p>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
 <% end %>
```

The select tag works if I take away the "f." right before it.  But if I take that away, it won't go to the user object.  If I put the "f." in, it says:

```
undefined method `select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f950db434e0>
```

I've seen some stackoverflow questions that are similar but don't help.  The documentation mentions this briefly but it is too complicated for a newbie like myself to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select_tag` is the basic ActionView helper for creating `<select>` elements. When working with form builder elements, you generally want the builder's `#select` method instead, e.g.:

`<%= f.select :how_did_you_hear, [["Bing", :bing], ...`

The form builder method calls `select_tag` as part of the build operation, but it names the element correctly so that the result that is passed back when the form is submitted is included as part of the `params` hash in a way that makes it easy to update your resource.

This assumes that your model has a `how_did_you_hear` attribute, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's `f.select`, not `f.select_tag`. 
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models